# How to make Qt Creator's jom.exe to copy files in paths with spaces?

Tags: windows, qt, makefile, copy, qt-creator

When I put in my `.pro` file

```
INSTALLS += INSTALL
INSTALL.files += install/**
INSTALL.path = bin
```

The `jom.exe install` command tries to copy the files using absolute paths

```
copy /y c:\Some Project\install\QtGui4.dll c:\Some Project\bin
```

this fails with

> The number of parameters is invalid

A better command would be quoting the paths

```
copy /y "c:\Some Project\install\QtGui4.dll" "c:\Some Project\bin"
```

which succedes. How to make jom.exe quote the absolute paths or to use relative paths instead?

Comment: I tried `$$quote()` to no avail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QMake doesn't handle spaces in paths very well. Sooner or later one always runs into issues when using a source or build directory with spaces in it. In my experience, fighting those issues is futile. I strongly suggest QMake users to put all source code into a path without spaces.